# Issue with unordered lists and ::selection formatting in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am using the following CSS to modify the color of highlighted text:

```
*::selection {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
*::-moz-selection {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}​
```

In Chrome when you highlight an unordered list the bullets have the default colors
[image: example]

Example: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tarLL/)

Is this a bug or can you use CSS to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like `::selection` is going to make it into the spec, so it makes sense that not a lot of attention was paid to this behaviour.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

> 7.3. Blank
>
> This section intentionally left blank. (This section previously
>   defined a ::selection pseudo-element.)